# bind multiple id using on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a id="abc">First</a>
<a id="xyz">Second</a>

$('body').on('click','#a,#b',function(){
btn = $(this).attr('id');
if(btn == "abc"){ //do something };
});
```

Why my above code worked when I click abc id but not the later button? Did I bind it wrongly?

Comment: Maybe because you have a condition `if` and check if it's `abc` to do something ?

Comment: Uhhh, the selector in  your `.on()` function doesn't match either of the links in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selectors are not correct and do not match your IDs:

```js
$('body').on('click','#abc,#xyz',function(){
    var btn = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(btn);
    if(btn === "abc") {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="abc">First</a>
<a id="xyz">Second</a>
```